# How do I get my code to repeat in a loop?

Tags: python

```
str = input("Enter the String")
l = len(str)
p = l-1
index = 0
while index < p:
    if str[index] == str[p]:
        index = index + 1
        p = p-1
        print("String is a Palindrome")
        break
    else:
        print("String is not a Palindrome")
        break
```

i need this to be able to ask the user if they would like to repeat the process or not but i cant figure it out because every time i try it only repeats the string "string is not a palindrome"

Comment: don't use str as a variable name. because it is a builtin name from python (to create a string)

Comment: Add your attempt at making it repeat.

Comment: @ppwater mention the reason: str shall not be used, because it is a builtin name from python (to create a string)

Comment: In general: if you end every code path in an iteration with `break` it's not going to loop.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this:

```
while True:
    user_input = input("Enter the String")
    l = len(user_input)
    p = l-1
    index = 0
    while index < p:
        if user_input[index] == user_input[p]:
            index = index + 1
            p = p-1
            print("String is a Palindrome")
            break
        else:
            print("String is not a Palindrome")
            break
    gonext = input("continue?(no to exit) ")
    if gonext == "no":
        break
    elif gonext == "yes":
        continue
```

add a input and if statement to ask the user, and while True to repeat.

and str is a built-in from Python, so don't use it as variable name.

Comment: Would be better to replace the variable name, with something like `user_input` to avoid any built-in type confusion

Comment: Also, I think the logic is still wrong. "anna", "kayak", "civic" should be recognized as palindromes.

Comment: yes @dbrrt , but the OP said i need this to be able to ask the user if they would like to repeat the process so I just fixed the repeating part

Comment: Fair enough :) , now at least it repeats the process

Comment: @dbrrt your example are correctly claimed as palindromes, but the logic is still wrong. check also my answer. problems occur by just checking first and last character (adsa is classified as palindrome)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your code to be able to repeat any task, you need to wrap it into a loop. Also you shouldn't use `str` as a name for a variable, because that name is used in python to create a new string.

one possible solution would be

```py
repeat = True

while repeat:
    # your code
    
    repeat = input("repeat? (y for yes, everything else is tretaed as no)\n") == "y"
```

Further, I want to point out, that your code is not doing what you expect.
A palindrome is defined as a String which reads backwards the same as forwards.
In your code, you are actually just testing whether the first and last character are the same. In the `if` branch, the problem is not solved. The positive result can only be given at the end of the loop.
Also, you don't cover the empty string (no output at all), which I would consider as a palindrome.
some cases you could test:

- ada -> correct positive
- asd -> correct negative
- asda -> false positive
- ""  -> nothing at all
  -a[arbitray string]a -> positive?

A correct implementation of the palindrome check would be something like this:

```py
user_input = input("Enter the String\n")
    
    isPalindrome = True
    for i in range(len(user_input)//2):       # check till center from both ends
        if user_input[i] != user_input[-i-1]: # index -1 is last character
            isPalindrome = False
            break
    
    if isPalindrome:
        print("String is a Palindrome")
    else:
        print("String is not a Palindrome")
```

Comment: I thought the question was how to repeat, not how to fix the logic?

Comment: @ppwater yes that wasn't asked, but I think pointing out that his code is not doing what is expected would be nice (and it is a pretty basic problem considered in many introduction courses, so I assume him to be a new coder). Also his last sentence indicates that he noticed the problem partially